# Android Gmail api : How to access a gmail account that is not added to the device s gmail account

Tags: android, gmail-api

While using the Gmail apis is it possible to pass "password" from my app.
What i see is that the credentials ( accountname / email and password ) are internally taken from the google accounts added to the device. (Is this understanding correct ). My requirement is to let the user add his email / and password directly in my app .can the user access a gmail account which is not added to devices gmail acccounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Gmail REST API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) to get basic access to any Gmail account which is not registered on the device, but you must use [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) to authenticate the user.

Alternatively, you could implement a POP or IMAP client in your app, but the user needs to [explicitly enable access](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960) in their Gmail account.

It might be helpful if you explain in your question *why* you need access to the user's email - what does your App do with access to a user's email that a normal email client doesn't?

Comment: I am doing a mail client app. I do not see an option to give the password in GMAIL RSET apis. What i see is that it takes the password from android account manager